# Fill in 0 for named vector

Tags: r, string, match

Suppose I have the following:

```
all_variable <- c("a","b","d")

all_variable
[1] "a" "b" "d"

myvec <- setNames(c(1),"b")

myvec
b 
1
```

Is there a clean way to obtain this:

```
expected_output <- setNames(c(0,1,0),all_variable)

expected_output 
a b d 
0 1 0
```

which fills in 0 if `all_variable` not in `names(myvec)`.

Note that `myvec` is actually extracted from `table("b")` so the following works:

```
table("b"|> factor(levels=all_variable))

a b d 
0 1 0
```

Therefore, I am mainly interested in solution by directly manipulating `myvec` and `all_variable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume that the question is asking that the `b` component of the result should hold the value of the `b` component of `myvec` and all other components should be 0.  In the question `myvec` contains the value 1 but if it contained 99 then we would want `setNames(c(0, 99, 0), c("a", "b", "d"))` as the result.

In the following code the first argument to `replace` is a named vector of three 0's. It replaces the name(s) specified in the second argument with `myvec`.

```
c(replace(0 * table(all_variable)[all_variable], names(myvec), myvec))
## a b d 
## 0 1 0
```

If the order of the resulting elements does not matter or if it is known that the names are sorted than we could remove the `[all_variable]` .

```
c(replace(0 * table(all_variable), names(myvec), myvec))
## a b d 
## 0 1 0
```

We can remove the c(...) if it is ok that the result is a table object.

If what is wanted is that the `b` component of the result should be 1 regardless of its value in `myvec` then use

```
c(table(c(all_variable, names(myvec)))[all_variable]) - 1
```

and again we can omit `[all_variable]` and `c(...)` under the same conditions as previously.

Answer (score 3):

`match` all_variable with `names` of myvec, option `nomatch=0`, `setNames` from all_variable.

```
match(all_variable, names(myvec), nomatch=0) |> setNames(all_variable)
# a b d 
# 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below

```
all_variable %>%
    setNames(+(. == "b"), .)
```

or

```
all_variable %>%
    setNames(+(. %in% "b"), .)
```

which should give

```
a b d
0 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- setNames(rep(0, length(all_variable)), all_variable)
x[names(myvec)] <- myvec
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you please check this if this helps

```r
all_variable <- c("a","b","d")

# assign values to the vector
expected_output <- c(0,1,0)

# assign the names to the vector
names(expected_output) <- all_variable

# output

a b d 
0 1 0
```